# Fetch only specific values from an array in a cleaner way

Tags: javascript

I have the following array in javascript

```
const arr = [
            0:{"name":"a","id":1}
            1:{"name":"b","id":2}  
             ......
```

So I would like to fetch only id's from arr

so to do this am doing

```
 let items = [];
 for (let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
  items[i] = arr[i].id
 }

 return items
```

The above works. But is there a better cleaner way to do the above without the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map()` method and return new array of `id`'s only.

```js
const arr = [{"name":"a","id":1}, {"name":"b","id":2} ] 
var ids = arr.map(({id}) => id);
console.log(ids)
```

Comment: the curly brace inside `map()` returns ids as **id inside array** instead of **array of object**. can you please explain?

Comment: It takes `id` property from current object in loop. Its ES6 property shorthand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` as well.

```
let items = []
arr.forEach((a)=>items.push(a.id))
console.log(items)
```